# Android Video View turns black

Tags: android, video

This seems to be a very common problem, but I couldn't search for it on SO.

I have a simple `videoview` and it play video from a mp4 file. It continously plays video and loop through the video.

Problem is when playing I went to settings and came back then video turns black.

**This is my Code:**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    // Load and start the movie
    Uri video1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.videoplayback);
    video.setVideoURI(video1);
    video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
    video.start();
```

I don't want anything special in this, just a full screen of video playback which loops video till user tap back button.

Comment: Settings mean settings of phone from top bar, and it happen for everything i open above my application and when I close it my video view is black.

Comment: you need to set current position on onPause and start with onResume with a new position

Comment: I had the same problem, use mediaPlayer instead

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private int stopPosition;
   private VideoView splashVideoView;  <-- my Video view
```

in `onCreate`

```
 //video player

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            stopPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
        }



  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        splashVideoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
        splashVideoView.start();
    }

// This gets called before onPause so pause video here.
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        stopPosition = splashVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
        splashVideoView.pause();
        outState.putInt("position", stopPosition);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  private int videoViewStopPosition ;

   @Override
    protected void OnPause(){
    super.onPause();
    videoViewStopPosition = vidView.getCurrentPosition();
    vidView.pause();
    }



  @Override
    protected void OnResume() {
     super.onResume();
     vidView.seekTo(videoViewStopPosition);
     vidView.start();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found that the main reason for that was the use of `FrameLayout` as the parent layout. I changed it into `RelativeLayout` as parent layout of the `VideoView` and the problem get solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Video view in `onResume()` also. Try this:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        setVideoBackground();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

        setVideoBackground();
    }

   private void setVideoBackground(){
       video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
       // Load and start the movie
       Uri video1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.videoplayback);
       video.setVideoURI(video1);
       video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
       mp.setLooping(true);
    }
  });
       video.start(); 
}
```